# PL/SQL how to add stars to a variable v_asterisk for every 1000$ of the employees salary

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE TABLE emp as (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES);
  ALTER TABLE emp
  ADD (stars VARCHAR(50));
     DECLARE
       v_empno EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE  :=176;
       v_asterisk  EMP.STARS%TYPE := '';
       v_sal EMP.SALARY%TYPE;
     BEGIN
       SELECT salary INTO v_sal
       FROM emp
       WHERE employee_id = v_empno;
       END;
```

How do i modify this to make v_asterisk get a star for every 1000$ of the employees salary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//just found out that is like this:

```
DECLARE
v_empno EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE  :=176;
v_asterisk EMP.STARS%TYPE := '';
v_sal EMP.SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(ROUND(salary/1000),0) INTO v_sal
FROM EMP
WHERE employee_id = v_empno;
FOR i IN 1..v_sal 
LOOP
v_asterisk:=v_asterisk||'*';
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use the LPAD or RPAD function, e.g.

```
v_asterisk := LPAD('*', FLOOR(salary/1000), '*');
```

Use FLOOR, ROUND or CEIL depending on how you want to treat portions of $1000.